# how to pass object in soap request

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2

In one of my app I want to send an `Object` to WCF service. This `Object` binds three data. I don't know how to send it.

I have tried

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapObject map = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "New Role");
map.addProperty("RoleID", "ROLEAAAA0001");
map.addProperty("RoleName", "MOB_Gunaseelan");
map.addProperty("ActionBy", "Gunaseelan");
request.addSoapObject(map);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
try {
    transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
} catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}

SoapFault fault = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
System.out.println("Fault : " + fault.toString());
```

This way. Here I want to bind `RoleID`,`RoleName`,`ActionBy` as one Object. In WCF service my colleague convert this object as his comfortable object and then extracts it. So I want to bind. Is it possible friends. If possible means please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
int ArryIndex = 0;
SoapObject soReturn ;
String [] ParameterName = new String[3]; 
String [] ParameterValue = new String[3];

ParameterName[0] = "RoleID";   
ParameterValue[0] = ROLEAAAA0001;

ParameterName[1] = "RoleName";   
ParameterValue[1] = MOB_Gunaseelan;

ParameterName[2] = "ActionBy";   
ParameterValue[2] = Gunaseelan;

objWSConfig.SetURL(URL, WebService);
objWSConfig.SetSOAPAction(SoapAction, MethodName);
objWSConfig.SetWebService(WebService); 
objWSConfig.SetMethod(MethodName);

ws_Method = objWSConfig.getMethod();
ws_Namespace = objWSConfig.getNamespace();
ws_URL = objWSConfig.getURL(); 
ws_SOAPAction = objWSConfig.getSOAPAction();

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(ws_Namespace,ws_Method);

for(ArryIndex = 0 ; ArryIndex < ParameterName.length ; ArryIndex ++)
{
    PropertyInfo ParaObj = new PropertyInfo();
    ParaObj.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS;
    ParaObj.namespace = ws_Namespace;
    ParaObj.setName(ParameterName[ArryIndex].toString());
    ParaObj.setValue(ParameterValue[ArryIndex].toString());
    request.addProperty(ParaObj);     
}

System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false"); 

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.dotNet = true;
//envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
envelope.setAddAdornments(true);   

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(ws_URL);
androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");

androidHttpTransport.call(ws_SOAPAction, envelope); 
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;   
resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

Comment: Added +1, Thank you so much... I didn't try it.. Wait, I will come back. After checking I waill accept it.

Comment: `08-01 17:52:56.779: I/System.out(22392): Fault : SoapFault - faultcode: 's:Client' faultstring: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null` Same Exception bro.

Comment: i think this error is not from your side. you r getting error from server side. have you check that is your method is working properly ???

Comment: May I know How to check?

Comment: debug your web service from where you are accessing it.

Comment: I had deabug. The code is working perfectly till soapfault calling. How can I find where is error.

Comment: see this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093860/ksoap2-android-sending-data 
and 
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

Answer (score 0):

you should create a class which implements kvmserializable interface

[This is a tutorial for sending complex objects through ksoap2](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html)