# Pass Object to WCF service

Tags: android, wcf

I am totally new to WCF service. I don't know how pass complex type to WCF service.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
SoapObject result;
Button b;
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "InsertData";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IWCFMasterTable/InsertData";
private static String URL = "http://172.16.0.1:55355/WCFMasterTable.svc";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        MyClass MC = new MyClass(MainActivity.this);
        MC.execute("");
    }
}

class MyClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SoapObject> {
    JSONObject jobj;
    MainActivity activity;

    public MyClass(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected SoapObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            ClsMasterTable ct = new ClsMasterTable();
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            ct = ct.getData();
            System.out.println(ct.TableID);
            request.addProperty("args", ct);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER12);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try {
                transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SoapFault fault = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
            System.out.println("Fault : " + fault.toString());
            result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            System.out.println("result : " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
}
```

And

```
public class ClsMasterCaseType {
String ID, Name, Mark;

public ClsMasterCaseType getData() {
    Mark= "88";
    ID = "CTYPAAAA0005";
    Name= "Karthik";
    return this;
}
}
```

This way I have tried to pass complex type. But this throws following exception

```
08-08 12:53:42.376: W/System.err(7845): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 

com.elintsys.wcfservice.ClsMasterCaseType@40fcbdf0
08-08 12:53:42.376: W/System.err(7845):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:687)
08-08 12:53:42.376: W/System.err(7845):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:671)
08-08 12:53:42.386: W/System.err(7845):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:640)
08-08 12:53:42.386: W/System.err(7845):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:624)
08-08 12:53:42.386: W/System.err(7845):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:681)
08-08 12:53:42.386: W/System.err(7845):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:597)
08-08 12:53:42.386: W/System.err(7845):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:101)
```

[how to pass object in soap request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991857/how-to-pass-object-in-soap-request) I have tried this way too. Please help me friends. I wasted three days for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the WCF service expose WSDL metedata?

Answer (score 0):

i have made some changes in your code.

**1)**

> SoapSerializationEnvelope Envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
>                               SoapEnvelope.VER12);

change into

> SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new
>   SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

**2)**

> SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

change into

> SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

Comment: Have you got the solution?